# The "Outlook Web App"'s menus are only partly visible in Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, outlook-web-access

The "Outlook Web App"'s menus are only partly visible in Google Chrome. Example:

[image]

(the first few items in the reply menu are not visible)

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

What could the should be? The issue appeared around two weeks ago.

Comment: What if you remove the toolbars/hide the bookmark bar. If that doesn't work, the menu could have a stylesheet attribute to make is start at a negative Y index. Dev tools could help you debug

Comment: Sometimes, this also happens because of some extensions. After disabling all extensions, try it again. Maybe that helps. For me, similar but not the same problem was fixed after disabling `Grammarly` extension.

Comment: @DavidPostill Issue was on the browser side. Could you please reopen the question? I'll post the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @David This ended up being an issue with Chrome itself and Franck provided an answer on our site which didn't get carried back with the migration rejection.  Could you reopen this so he can add his answer here, where, IMO, the question belongs.

Comment: (sorry @FranckDernoncourt I thought the answer had originated over here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting Google Chrome with `--disable-extensions` fixes the issue, which suggested that one extension was because of this issue. (thanks Biku Balami for the idea)

After disabling extensions one by one (yes, that's tedious), I saw that the Google Chrome extension [Firebug Lite for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firebug-lite-for-google-c/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) is causing the issue. Disabling it fixed the issue.

[image]

-->

[image]

whereas with

[image]

-->

[image]

Note that on another computer of mine with the same operating system and the same version of Google Chrome, everything works fine and the extension Firebug Lite for Google Chrome didn't cause the issue.